# Can't access public property of a class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've made a public class with 3 properties. The code is as follows;

```
public class FileInformation
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this class to fill a Datagrid with files from a local folder. For that I'm using the following code;

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"db\");
        List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles("*.accdb").ToList();

        List<FileInformation> view1 = new List<FileInformation>();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            view1.Add(new FileInformation() { Name = file.Name, CreationTime = file.CreationTime, LastModified = file.LastWriteTime });
        }

        listview_openproject.ItemsSource = view1;
```

Now, I would like to be able to detect which files is selected in the datagrid, so I've tried with the following;

```
var selectedProject = listview_openproject.SelectedValue;
```

This gives me an object with 3 properties - Name, Creationtime and LastModified. So far, so good. I want to access the attibute "Name", but I am not able to do so. I expected that i could simply write;

```
var selectedProjectName = selectedProject.Name;
```

But this is not working. How can I access this property?

Screenshot from VS:

[image]

Comment: tried `var selectedProject = (FileInformation) listview_openproject.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Try with _var selectedProject = listview_openproject.SelectedValue as FileInformation;_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property returns the entire object that your list is bound to. Use this property instead:

```
FileInformation fi = (FileInformation)listview_openproject.SelectedItem;
String name = fi.Name;
```

Comment: This is one of the cases where the check for null is wrong. `fi` should never be null, and if it was then there's a bug somewhere

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for the insight, that's right